# Type checking casting of Struct and Class comparison

Tags: swift, casting

In Class vs Struct documentation https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html, one of the differences between Struct and Class is

**Type casting enables you to check and interpret the type of a class instance at runtime.**

I'm trying to understand what that means. Can't really figure out even by looking at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html

I tried the following codes

```
protocol Aprotocol { }

struct Bstruct: Aprotocol {
    func bDoThis() {
        print("B do this")
    }
}

class Cclass: Aprotocol {
    func cDoThis() {
        print("C do this")
    }
}

func dothing(a: Aprotocol) {
    
    switch a {
    case is Bstruct:
        print("this is B")
        (a as? Bstruct)?.bDoThis()
    case is Cclass:
        print("this is C")
        (a as? Cclass)?.cDoThis()
    default:
        print("this is not B")
    }
}

dothing(a: Bstruct())
dothing(a: Cclass())
```

The `is` and `as` works for both Bstruct and Cclass. to me, that's **Type Checking** and **Type Casting**, which seems to work for both Struct and Class. Did I miss anything? What's the exact meaning of "**Type casting enables you to check and interpret the type of a class instance at runtime.**" ?

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
let v : UIView = UIButton()
(v as? UIButton)?.setTitle("howdy", for: .normal)
```

That works because UIView is a superclass (and UIButton is one of its subclasses). You cannot do that with a struct, because a struct can never be a "superstruct"; there is no inheritance hierarchy among structs.

*Your* code, on the other hand, is about protocol and adopter, which is a totally different thing. None of your code downcasts a struct *or* a class; what you do is downcast a protocol, and of course you can downcast it to *any* adopter, be it class, struct, or enum. But as I say, that is not what that passage in the book is about.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt. Can I say the **Type casting enables you to check and interpret the type of a class instance at runtime** is an implication of **Inheritance enables one class to inherit the characteristics of another.** The "type of class" literally refers to "class"... hence it is obvious a "struct" cannot do that since it is never a class right?

Comment: Yes, I hope that's what I said in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt. I didn't think of that initially, as it seems redundant to state something that can be inferred from the first statement directly.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Given struct can't inherit a struct, it is obvious, one cannot find a sub-struct, as there's no way to do that in the first place. For class instance, it could be an inherited instance of another class, so one can check if it is a subclass. Hence it does sound this **Type casting enables you to check and interpret the type of a class instance at runtime** is part of **Inheritance enables one class to inherit the characteristics of another.**

Comment: @Elye I think it’s as simple as “classes offer inheritance” and that “type casting enables you to check and interpret” instances of them at runtime.